# Validate for empty row in Android

Tags: android

I have a table in which 5 rows are there. But I have to feed the value of row in the database in which values are filled. It can be 2nd, 3rd or all. So how would I find out and validate the same. The rows are not generating dynamically. The rows are already in layout with some ids. I know it's weird but requirement is this only. Please suggest me how can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

For that you have some alternative,

- I think you should insert default record into the field so that will be easy instead of validating, if you think that is good.
- When get the result from the DB just put the single condition

`String name = Db.get_name().toString();`

```
if(name!=null)
{
Row_TextView.setText(name);
}
else
{
Row_TextView.setText("-"); // or what ever you want to set
}
```

- Here is [database example](http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/sqlite-database-example/)

Try it i hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

- What you need is a `Cursor` to read data from the db
- Then loop through the fetched data (if `'getCount()>0'` then `while(!cursor.isAfterLast)`)
- For each row check if the data is present in specific columns in your db and if not then do insert it in the db